# Query to search a particular string in single table in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I need a query in oracle 11g that will search all the columns of a table for a particular string and give the result.

I have tried a query given below and it worked for me...

```
SELECT * FROM account
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID like'%gaurav%'
OR    ACCOUNT_NAME like'%gaurav%'
OR    PARENT_ACCOUNT like'%gaurav%'
OR WEBSITE LIKE '%gaurav%'
OR TYPE LIKE'%gaurav%'
  OR   DESCRIPTION LIKE'%gaurav%'
 OR    ACCOUNT_OWNER LIKE'%gaurav%'
  OR    PHONE LIKE'%gaurav%'
OR    STD_CODE LIKE'%gaurav%'
OR    EMPLOYEES LIKE'%gaurav%';
```

but I need a more simplified solution...as I am having only 10 columns in my table so this solution is okay but what if I have 30-40 columns in my table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table with 30-40 columns you should normalize the database: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php and you might not need to check all columns (phone for example). Your solution is fine :)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion ...but my data is already normalized and i am having thirty one columns in my table...and writing all those column names is not a feasible solution i think....is there any other sol. like a function or a procedure that would help in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution that is generic, repeatable, and simple enough to use, then implement a table function with

- input parameters of: "table name", "searched string"
- result of: collection of tuple {"rowid", "column name with the match"}

Inside the table function you can implement the functionality you need via means of dynamic SQL.

As for the terms used above ...

- collection: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005
- "tuple" = record ... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005
- dynamic SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011
- (pipelined) table functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS915

Comment: thanks for your suggestion "nop77svk" but i didn't get it exactly, actually i am new in database so can you please explain me  more what you are trying to say.can you please write a query for this so it would become more easy for me to understnad

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can't. It can't be solved via single query.

As for the table function, it is a rather long piece of PL/SQL code. Find yourself a skilled Oracle dev near you and have him write such a table function for you. That would be better.